# Can junit write to disk outside of its sandbox

Tags: android, unit-testing

I'm trying to write a script to make our UI unit tests record network calls during their first run, save that file to disk, and replay it on subsequent runs if the file is checked in.

In order to do this, I've created a rule with the intention of having that rule create a new file in our assets directory, but while I have the information I need, I can't figure out how to get it to save to the machine running the test.

Here's the code from my latest attempt:

```
val file = File("/Users/{me}/AndroidStudioProjects/{my app}/src/androidTest/assets/generated/{test name}")
file.mkdirs()
file.createNewFile()
```

It tries to save the file to the phone rather than to anywhere I can get it.  Any idea how I can have a junit test save to disk in some place where I can access it?

Edit:  Okay, I'm dumb.  My test code is not running on my machine; it's running on the phone.  My question then becomes: How do I write to the computer from an Android junit test?

Workaround: since I want this to be part of a process that is currently somewhat manual, I'm saving the file to external storage and using ADB pull from the project root to the "generated" directory.  I'd like to automate the movement step, but for now it's working as an MVP.